# Variable inside a macro

Tags: unreal-engine4

How do I create variables inside of a macro? I've created a macro library with some macros and now I am trying to figure out how to create a local variable that exists inside a macro for the lifetime of the macro. Perhaps theres a way to store that data somewhere else?

Comment: So I can access variables as long as It exists in the blueprint that I derive my macro library from. All I have to do is keep the naming scheme for my blueprints the same so that I can reuse the macro libraries in all my projects. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing the Macro, use the [Inputs collection of the Details panel](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/Macros/) to create a dummy variable of the required type.

Do not check the By-Ref checkbox.

Leave it unconnected when calling the Macro.

Use the variable like any other variable.

---

If you are not using latent functions like delay or timeline, use functions instead.

I create function libraries anytime I need code reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying function libraries now.

Comment: When I was creating macros inside a macro library, I had to pass in self so that I could get or set a variable belonging to a blueprint. This created a few extra "Target based get variables".  This meant I always had to drag from self (input) to set or get a variable before passing it around. Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: @Ben, Maybe.  If a macro or function is coupled to a specific BP consider using a function defined a BP base class instead.

Comment: With functions, pass the variables themselves, not the BP(self) whenever possible. Saves on casting and provides more flexible code for re-use. If your function needs to change a value, pass by-ref.

Comment: How do you define a function as a BP base class? Are you saying you are making the first input to the function of the target type?eg. If you are working with an AIController class, then set the first input as AIControlller and work from that?

Comment: If the type is always known to be an AIController, then no use the class directly.  What I was saying was if you have a function passing an Actor only to call GetActorPosition for a Vector3, you could extend the functionality to include any SceneComponent class by accepting a Vector3 directly instead of an Actor. It all depends on how coupled you want your library to be. I am in the mindset of project to project.